# My code is running perfectly fine but is giving me an error "$ is invalid for atomic vectors" in mapIds function, what can I do?

Tags: r, annotations, r-markdown, genetics

I have a data frame exp_mean and I'm using mapIds for annotation of my genes and it worked in markdown and assigned the right annotation to all the genes but doesn't seem to work once I knit to pdf.

```
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
exp_mean$entrez <- mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db, exp_mean$Gene, 'ENTREZID', 'SYMBOL')

#mean has all the genes and the mean of expression levels 
exp_mean <- data.frame(mean)
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
exp_mean$entrez <- mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db, exp_mean$Gene, 'ENTREZID', 'SYMBOL')
```

(this worked fine btw but doesnt seem to knit to pdf)

it's giving

```
error $ is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: If `exp_mean` is a `"matrix"`, your first two lines will fail. Try `exp_mean <- cbind(exp_mean, entrez=mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db, exp_mean[, 'Gene'], 'ENTREZID', 'SYMBOL'))`. If it just fails during knitting, you might have a working directory issue, means that `exp_mean` couldn't be found due to different paths. Try to replace the code with `summary(exp_mean)` or something to check.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! its working now, but can u tell me why you used cbind?

Comment: The `$` function only works with list-like objects such as `"data.frame"`s. To matrices you can `cbind` (named) columns. Running the short examples in `?cbind` and `?\`$\`` might be a good practice for you.